# Android: What is the best way to restore alarms after reboot?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-reboot

I know how to use the BOOT COMPLETED Broadcast receiver but I wonder what exactly should i do? How to save the time of the alarms given that i have an unknown number of alarms all set by the user? And how do i restore them in the Broadcast receiver?

Comment: Store them in a database, and when you boot up recreate them by reading them in from the db

Comment: Thank you! I learned how to do it and it worked!